# How to clear screen from simple C program?

Tags: c, coding-style, header

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

rec();

main() 
{
    int a, fact;
    char q, n, y;
    printf("\nEnter any number ");
    scanf("%d", & a);
    fact = rec(a);
    printf("Factorial value = %d\n", fact);
    printf("do you want to exit.....(y/n):");
    scanf("%s" ,&q);
    if (q == 'n')
    {
        system("cls");
        main();
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

rec(int x) 
{
    int f;
    if (x == 1) 
        return 1;
    else 
        f = x * rec(x - 1);

    return f;
}
```

I'm using code blocks but I don't know how to clear the screen. I searched then found `system("cls");` within header file `#include<cstdlib>`, but it shows the error `cstdlib: no such file of directory`. What should I do ?

Comment: When in doubt, please do visit these links, to know, which function belongs to which header file or which header file has which function :-)  [Alphabetical Index](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/index.html) and [Headers Index](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/headers.html)

Comment: `main()` -> `int main(void)` and `rec();` -> `int rec(int x);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearing the screen is outside the purview of a normal C program. It depends on the operating system.

For windows, you should look into [conio](/questions/tagged/conio).

For unix, look into [curses](/questions/tagged/curses) or [termios](/questions/tagged/termios).

`system()` always launches a sub-shell which may or may not have any effect on the environment of the parent program. You *do* need a *system-call*, but *not* a `system()` call.

---

I didn't always know this. I once (long ago) suggested in comp.lang.c that someone should try `system("exit");` to close the window around the DOS program. But that, of course, cannot work. And I was quickly advised to test my code before posting. :)

Answer (score 9):

Change

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

to

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

`cstdlib` is a **C++ header file**, and thus will be **unusable in C**.

Comment: just a flash of another screen comes n went off. but the curren screen remains as it is without clearing screen

Comment: @RahulSubedi That is an unrelated problem really.. Looks like `system` is opening a new terminal instead of using the current one. Have you tried running the program from the command line instead of from eclipse?

Comment: @RahulSubedi luser droog has some insights about your clearing the screen problem

Comment: I have tried this but I am getting the error: `sh: cls: command not found`

Comment: @Maximilian try `clear` instead. That needs to be a func supported by your shell

Answer (score 4):

you have lots of problems in your code....

but for the specific problem, try  `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: #include <stdlib.h> also didnt worked. just a flash of another window come n goes away n the current window remains same without clearing screen

Answer (score -1):

use the `#include<stdlib.h>` that's where the clear screen function is defined.

Answer (score -1):

To use `system("cls")` you need the header `<iostream>`. This will allow all `system()` types to execute. Unsure if it is a C++ header file, but it works for the compiler that I use.