# save display before calling a CDKpopup using C

Tags: c, terminal, ncurses

Im trying to edit a program that capture user input. My intention is to add a function counting to a certain time. When it meet a timeout, a popup should be displayed. After that, the user should see back its previous shell/display. My problem is:

If the popup appear while the user are running vi, the display in that vi mode are hidden after the popup are destroyed.

**Expectation:** the user should have the same display as before the popup

[image: before popup]
Before the popup appear

[image: after popup]
After the popup destroyed

If the user are writing in a shell, it does not display the *bash name* (I do not know what its called. eg. **fikrie@fikrie-VirtualBox:~/mysoftware/src$**).

**Expectation:** the user should see the same display as before.

[image: does not display bash name]
at the top line, the command (id) is displayed without bash name. I need to make the display same as the third line.

Im writing the code in C language and I'm using cdk library(ncurses) to do the popup. This is the function that create the popup.

```
int call_warning(struct tm *warning_display)
{
    char *mesg[4];
    WINDOW *cursesWin;
    CDKSCREEN *cdkscreen;
    char *buttons[1]  = { "[ OK ]" };
    char enddatetime[1024];

    strftime(enddatetime, sizeof(enddatetime), "%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S%p", warning_display);

    mesg[0] = "<C>----------------------";
    mesg[1] = "<C>Your timeout is near";
    mesg[2] = enddatetime;
    mesg[3] = "<C>----------------------";

    //I have tried using def_shell_mode() here
    cursesWin = initscr();
    cdkscreen = initCDKScreen(cursesWin);
    initCDKColor();

    while (1) {
            popupDialogWithColor(cdkscreen, mesg, 4, buttons, 1, "</2>");
            destroyCDKScreen(cdkscreen);
            werase(cursesWin);
            wrefresh(cursesWin);
            endCDK();
            endwin();
            break;
    }
    //I tried using reset_shell_mode() here and removing system("clear");
    system("clear"); //tried using refresh() as well. Didnt do the job
    return 0;
}
```

From what i read in the manual guide, the def_shell_mode() will save the prior terminal settings so they can be restored during the call to endwin(). I tested using that but it doesnt solve my problem. I did google on how to clear screen using C. From the result, its either use curse or termios. I dont think termios is a good approach because I want to let the user continue its previous session and not making a new one. So my only option is curses. Is there any function in ncurses that can do this?

EDIT: After a few days trying, I found out CDK is the one causing problem. So I change my code to use curses function instead. The idea to do it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643713/doing-initscr-in-a-loop-causes-error-initialisation/29646397#29646397).

[How do you clear console screen in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347770/how-do-you-clear-console-screen-in-c)
[How to clear screen from simple C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102976/how-to-clear-screen-from-simple-c-program)

Comment: Terminal-settings do not include the contents of the screen (they refer to settings which you can manipulate with `stty`).  There is no portable way to restore the screen contents.

Comment: @ThomasDickey. Thank you. I will put an update here if found anything helpful from stty.