# doing initscr() in a loop causes error initialisation

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I'm trying to make a simple ncurses program to display a box with messages. Im following this [link](http://www.paulgriffiths.net/program/c/curwin1.php) and it works well. The problem that I'm having is that if I put the whole code in a function and call it in a loop, the initialisation is having an error. As far as I know, if I called `endwin()` at the end of the function, there shouldn't be any problem calling the `initscr()` again. Am I missing a function to enable the `initscr()` to be called again?

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>

int call()
{
    WINDOW *mainwin, *childwin;
    int ch;

    if ((mainwin = initscr()) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error initialising ncurses.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    noecho();
    curs_set(FALSE);

    keypad(mainwin, TRUE);

    mvaddstr(childwin, 1, 6, "Warning! Press q to exit");
    mvaddstr(childwin, 2, 15, "{ OK }");
    refresh();
    while( (ch = getch()) != 'q') {
            refresh();
    }

    delwin(mainwin);
    endwin();
    refresh();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
            call();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I've put the header file. Change the code to be more simpler

Comment: Can share the error message here?

Comment: @niyasc it just print the error that i wrote in the code. Error initialising ncurses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample program does not call `initscr` more than one.  However, it does not show the `#include` lines either (necessary to compile), so perhaps it is not the program which was actually run.

Regarding a problem calling `initscr` (once or more than once), there are at least two possibilities:

- you are using some other implementation of curses (e.g., a Unix one such as HPUX).  As noted in [X/Open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/initscr.html), *portable programs must not call initscr more than once*.
- the `TERM` variable is not set to a usable value.  As usual, the [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html) explains what the function does, and why it might fail.

Comment: the intscr is in a function and I'm calling that function repeatedly. Doesn't that mean initscr is called more than once? Anyway, the things that you pointed out did help me on solving this problem. Thanks a lot!